# Ocultar tabla al escribir en un input

Tags: javascript, php

Tengo un buscador donde obtengo y muestro datos de una base de datos MySQL con PHP y AJAX. Para eso me he guiado de [esta página](https://mimentevuela.wordpress.com/2015/08/09/busqueda-instantanea-con-ajax-php-y-mysql/).

¿Cómo haría para que cuando escriba alguna letra o palabra en el *input*, mi otra tabla se oculte solo cuando estoy realizando una búsqueda?

Aquí está el script que uso

```
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#ItemList_search").html('');
            });
            
            function buscar() {
                var textoBusqueda = $("input#search").val();
            
                if (textoBusqueda != "") {
                    $.post("modulos/php/search.php", {valorBusqueda: textoBusqueda}, function(mensaje) {
                        $("#ItemList_search").html(mensaje);
                    }); 
                } else { 
                    $("#ItemList_search").html('');
                    };
            };
```

Mi otra tabla tiene como ID: `id="ItemList"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías usar el evento [input](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) que se dispara cuando hay cambios en el campo, ya sea por escribir, cortar, pegar, etc.

Ocultas con [$.hide()](https://api.jquery.com/hide/) y muestras después con [$.show()](https://api.jquery.com/show/)

```
// Asignar evento para ocultar tabla al modificar input
$('#search').on('input', function() {
    // Ocultar tabla
    $('#ItemList').hide();
});

function buscar() {
    // Mostrar tabla al realizar la búsqueda
    $('#ItemList').hide();
    var textoBusqueda = $("input#search").val();

    if (textoBusqueda != "") {
        $.post("modulos/php/search.php", {valorBusqueda: textoBusqueda}, function(mensaje) {
            $("#ItemList_search").html(mensaje);
        }); 
    } else { 
        $("#ItemList_search").html('');
    }
};
```

Ahora, el problema es que ya tienes un evento `keyup` que, en teoría, funciona de la misma forma que el sugerido y el comportamiento del script puede ser impredecible al tener esos dos eventos al mismo tiempo.

```
// No es recomendable tener onEVENTO="código"
<input type="text" name="busqueda" id="busqueda" value="" placeholder="" maxlength="30" autocomplete="off" onKeyUp="buscar();" />
```

Aparte, el uso de eventos en línea se considera mala práctica, porque dificulta el mantenimiento de tus proyectos. Lo más recomendable es eliminar ese evento de la etiqueta:

```
// No es recomendable tener onEVENTO="código"
<input type="text" name="busqueda" id="busqueda" value="" placeholder="" maxlength="30" autocomplete="off">
```

Asignar evento desde Javascript:

```
// Asignar evento para realizar la búsqueda
$('#search').on('input', buscar);

function buscar() {
    // Eliminar el contenido antes de realizar la búsqueda
    $('#ItemList').html('');
    var textoBusqueda = $("#search").val();

    if (textoBusqueda != "") {
        $.post("modulos/php/search.php", {valorBusqueda: textoBusqueda}, function(mensaje) {
            $("#ItemList_search").html(mensaje);
        }); 
    } // Ya no se necesita un else
};
```

### Notas:

El script que estás usando es muy antiguo y el rendimiento podría no ser el óptimo, porque en cada cambio del campo se van a ejecutar peticiones AJAX, sin tener en cuenta la velocidad de escritura del usuario, por lo que podrías tener varias peticiones ejecutándose al mismo tiempo.

*jQuery* tiene una extensión [autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote) que podría satisfacer tus necesidades y mejorar tanto el rendimiento como la experiencia del usuario.

Comment: Hola, entiendo que el script sea antiguo. Como podría optimizarlo? acerca del evento input que se dispara cuando hay cambios en el campo, si se oculta, pero creo que hace falta que cuando se borra el campo del input vuelva a aparecer la tabla.

Comment: @MarcosParedes, la primera opción de la respuesta no es recomendable, deberías intentar la segunda. Para optimizar, te recomiendo la extensión _autocomplete_ de _jQuery_.

Answer (score 0):

Te comparto un ejemplo funcional de como lo puedes realizar en tu caso con Javascript y con jQuery.

Lo que hacemos es agregarle un el evento input a nuestro input de busqueda cuando ya se halla cargado el html.

Se hace con dicho evento, ya que este se dispara o se ejecuta cuando el value tiene cambios, mientras que con el evento change toca esperar a perder el foco del input para que se dispare.

te comparto una url de apoyo, para que comprenda el comportamiento del evento input. [evento input](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event)

```js
/**
 * Con javascript modificando el style del elemento
 **/
window.onload = () => {
  document.getElementById('searchJS').addEventListener('input', (e) => {
    if (e.target.value !== undefined && e.target.value !== null && e.target.value.trim().length > 0) {
      document.getElementById('ItemListJS').style = 'display: none;';
    } else {
      document.getElementById('ItemListJS').style = 'display: flex;';
    }
  });
};


/**
 * Con jQuery - Version usada: 3.3.1
 **/
$(document).ready(() => {
  $('#searchJQ').on('input', (e) => {
    if (e.target.value !== undefined && e.target.value !== null && e.target.value.trim().length > 0) {
      $('#ItemListJQ').css({
        'display': 'none'
      });
    } else {
      $('#ItemListJQ').css({
        'display': 'flex'
      });
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label for="searchJS">Prueba con Javascript:</label>
<input id="searchJS" name="searchJS" type="text">
<br>
<br>
<span id="ItemListJS">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum perspiciatis praesentium repellendus tempore quis eum porro laborum itaque! Consectetur sit sequi sed rerum sapiente ratione nobis voluptate, excepturi debitis harum.</span>
<hr>
<br>
<label for="searchJQ">Prueba con jQuery:</label>
<input id="searchJQ" name="searchJQ" type="text">
<br>
<br>
<span id="ItemListJQ">lors Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum perspiciatis praesentium repellendus tempore quis eum porro laborum itaque! Consectetur sit sequi sed rerum sapiente ratione nobis voluptate, excepturi debitis harum.</span>
```

También puedes mirar otras opciones de como ocultar y mostrar elementos en la siguiente ruta. [agregando estilo al elemento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3269136/how-to-add-style-displayblock-to-an-element-using-jquery)

Espero te sirva. Saludos